# Hot Mess: Conditional Statement with strncmp will not Execute

Tags: visual-c++

I feel like my code is what the kids would call a hot mess, but more like someone,i.e. me, took a fresh dump on everything. I wrote this in C++ to practice, but things a not happening the way I want it to.

```
//validation: check for other values other than three temp units
        } while ((strncmp(temp_data.current_temp, KELVIN, strlen(temp_data.current_temp)) +
            strncmp(temp_data.current_temp, CELSIUS, strlen(temp_data.current_temp)) +
            strncmp(temp_data.current_temp, FAHRENHEIT, strlen(temp_data.current_temp))==0) &&

            (strncmp(local_convert_temp, KELVIN, strlen(local_convert_temp)) +
            strncmp(local_convert_temp, CELSIUS, strlen(local_convert_temp)) +
            strncmp(local_convert_temp, FAHRENHEIT, strlen(local_convert_temp)) == 0));
```

I tried a different iteration using more of a conditional statement instead of simple arithmetic, but that didn't work either. I took the entire statement apart and each strncmp is returning a 0 value when the condition is met; with or without the macro. The situation is the same with this piece of the code:

```
strncmp(current_temp, CELSIUS, strlen(current_temp)) + strncmp(convert_temp, KELVIN, strlen(convert_temp)) == 0)
```

I tried taking the statement apart check to see if the in-block statement will execute if the condition is met and that works. The issue arise when I make the conditional statement more complex. What I am expecting is that when both conditions are met the statement will simply execute.

Comment: What did you hope to achieve by adding up return values of `strncmp`? The specific numbers `strncmp` returns are not specified - all you can rely on is that the number is less than zero if first string compares before the second, zero if they are equal, and greater than zero if the first compares after the second. So you are basically adding up random numbers, losing the useful signal in the process.

Comment: That doesn't make sense either. Surely `current_temp` cannot be equal to both `CELSIUS` and `KELVIN` at the same time, so the test is always false.

Comment: Input validition from user input. True, I don't think my code is effiecent; at this point I'm going for correctness. My initial approach was conditional statements with the OR operator: (strncmp(temp_data.current_temp, KELVIN, strlen(temp_data.current_temp)==0 || (strncmp(temp_data.current_temp, CELSIUS, strlen(temp_data.current_temp)==0...Honestly, I am brute-forcing the problem and try different solutions and maybe refine it to a workable solution.